# How can fix same origin issue after hosting successfully my Java fullstack web application

Tags: same-origin-policy

I was created an fullstack web application using react as frontend Java spring boot as backend. My SQL as db I was successfully completed my project but whenever I tried to deploy it , if I host backend or front any one of this and using that's url running another in  local development server.It running properly ly but if tired to host both . Whenever I tried to run that the front end is working but the request which is going to backend rest API is blocked by cros origin issue after that I configured it on spring boot but then it shows same origin issue while running the deployed site.

I used springboot as docker image to deploy. I deployed backend springboot api as docker image on render.com and deployed  frontend react app using netlify.com

Please tell me how to resolve that I had been stucked for three weeks for this .

I want to fix the issue of same origin in Java

fulstack web application

Comment: Please take the [tour]. See also [ask] and in your Question add a [mre]